# Why is my session ending?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have an ASP.NET web application I'm running with VS2010 that has session timeout configured for 20 minutes.
I leave a page running that does an ajax call every 2 minutes and has a [defibrillator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/Session_Defibrillator.aspx) implemented. With this setup, the session should never expire; and yet I find that 20 minutes later my session is still ending.

Does anybody know why that happens? And more importantly, can anybody tell me how to make sure the session never expires when the user is in that page?

---

EDIT: I changed the defibrillator so it now executes this code in javascript:

`setTimeout("location.href = '/Defibrillator.aspx?nocache=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*100000000001) + "';",60000);`

Still the same, so it's not a cache issue.
I'm running the site from VS directly (via the Debug "play" button), so it shouldn't be sharing an Application Pool, right?

Comment: Check whether your application shares the same Application Pool with another web applications (see IIS management console)

Comment: Could it be because of caching?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I had to resort to adding an autosave feature using ajax.
It's a sad day when StackOverflow can't give me an answer :(

---

EDIT: I finally found out what was causing the problem... it turned out that in some place in the masterpage the code was calling a rather obscure method that enforced a fixed timeout... so it wasn't anything that you could have helped me with. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the javascript is getting executed?  Check your access logs to see if the request is there.

Also inspect your cookies - I'd suspect that perhaps the session cookie is not getting updated, so you may need to reload the page occasionally in order to refresh it.

Update:  From the comments, it sounds like the session cookie as stored by the browser is not getting refreshed.  I'd suggest either reloading the page periodically, and perhaps changing the session timeout.  You'll have to balance the two depending on the usage patterns of the app.

Comment: I'm using Firefox with Firebug, and a call to http://localhost:60743/Defibrillator.aspx?nocache=85211572623 or such is added every minute to the Net tab. I'm not sure how to check the session cookie, but the reason why I need this page to be kept alive is because it's a large form that may take a long time to fill and shouldn't be saved in between, so reloading the page is a big no-no.

Comment: The web developer plugin has a way to view cookies, and I think there are a few other plugins that will do the same thing.

Comment: Ok, I tried that. I added a log to the Session_End event in the Global.asax and left it running all night. I found that it hit the event many times, but the session cookie still reads the same value.

Comment: Again, I need to keep the data entered by the user indefinitely, so whatever I do reloading the main page is out. The inner page in the defibrillator is constantly reloading, though. Changing the session timeout would only delay the issue, since it would only be a matter of time before the session ends. What I need here is a way to keep the main page alive indefinitely, without having to reload it.

Comment: If you need to keep the data entered by the user, I'd probably look at a database-backed session.  That way you can always reload the state next time the page loads.  Either that, or make the page stateless.

Comment: I think we're not looking at this in the right way. I mean, there is a page inside an iframe constantly refreshing, shouldn't that be enough to keep the session alive? Isn't there anything I can do to this page and this page alone that can avoid it dying? I really don't want to implement any complex solution that affects any other page than this one, since it's a pretty large site.